# Matching operators (e.g. ==, >=) with regular expressions

Tags: regex

I'm attempting to write a regex that will match the commonly used programming langauge operators. This is the regex string I'm using (it's part of a larger expression):

```
[>|<|>=|<=|==|!=]
```

This matches against ">", "<" but it doesn't match any of the others. I've tried escaping them like `\>\=` or `\=\=` but it doesn't make a difference.

I'm sure this is very simple and I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[ ] - match one character

( ) - match group of characters
```

so:

```
(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)
```

Comment: And, `|` in `[]` is treated as a normal char, not a metachar.

Comment: This might fail as well, depending on the Regex-Engines implementation. `(>=|<=|>|<|==|!=)` could be a better choice, so `>=` will be tried before `>`.

Comment: This was embarrassingly obvious. Thanks very much! I'll mark your post as the answer when the 10 minute limit is up.

Comment: @RenéKolařík - can u plz update your answer as per the suggestions of amon